# PyRadiomics: How to extract features from Gray Level Run Length Matrix using PyRadiomix library for a .jpg image

Tags: feature-extraction, glcm

I am unable to extract GLRLM features using the PyRadiomix library for a .jpg file. It has also a mask input, which is not clear to me.

```
import SimpleITK as sitk
from radiomics import glrlm
from radiomics import featureextractor

image = sitk.ReadImage('D:\Desert.jpg', imageIO="JPEGImageIO")
extractor = featureextractor.RadiomicsFeatureExtractor()
extractor = featureextractor.RadiomicsFeatureExtractor(binWidth=20, sigma=[1, 
             2, 3], verbose=True)
# Disable all feature classes, save firstorder
extractor.disableAllFeatures()
extractor.enableFeatureClassByName('glrlm')

extractor.enableFeaturesByName(glrlm=['SRE', 'LRE','GLN','GLNN','RLN','RLNN','RP','GLV','RV','RE','LGLRE','HGLRE','SRLGLE','SRHGLE','LRLGLRE','LRHGLRE'])
******result = extractor.execute(imagePath, labelPath)*******
```

I got this code from the PyRadiomics website. But at the last line, I can't understand the two parameters

Comment: Please, show us your code and the errors you are getting

Comment: @Tonechas I have added the code

Comment: @Tonechas pls help if u know about it

Comment: @Tonechas What will be the maskFilepath input for my jpg file? What it does actually?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://pyradiomics.readthedocs.io/en/latest/radiomics.html?highlight=execute#radiomics.featureextractor.RadiomicsFeatureExtractor.execute):

> `execute(imageFilepath, maskFilepath, label=None, label_channel=None, voxelBased=False)`
>
> Compute radiomics signature for provide image and mask combination. It comprises of
> the following steps:
>
> Parameters:
>
> - **imageFilepath** – SimpleITK Image, or string pointing to image file location
> - **maskFilepath** – SimpleITK Image, or string pointing to labelmap file location
> - **label** – Integer, value of the label for which to extract features. If not specified, last specified label is used. Default label is 1.
> - **label_channel** – Integer, index of the channel to use when maskFilepath yields a SimpleITK.Image with a vector pixel type. Default index is 0.
> - **voxelBased** – Boolean, default False. If set to true, a voxel-based extraction is performed, segment-based otherwise.

Therefore in the call

```py
result = extractor.execute(imagePath, labelPath)
```

`labelPath` plays the role of `maskFilepath` in the signature.

Comment: What will be the maskFilepath input for my jpg file? What it does actually?

Comment: It defines the region of interest (ROI) in the image

Comment: So, if I want to extract all features (mentioned in PyRadiomics) from the whole image, will I again pass the same SimpleITK Image as a second argument?

Comment: I don't think so. You could use the examples provided [here](https://github.com/AIM-Harvard/pyradiomics/tree/master/data) to get acquainted with pyradiomics. Note that the masks are those files whose name ends with `_label.nrrd`.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody would like to

> extract all features (mentioned in PyRadiomics) from the whole image

like OP, then pass to `maskFilepath` an image (in the size of the original image) full of `ones` (see default label value of `execute` method).
Note that extracted features such as `Shape` may become meaningless.